# .Php file to img file (.png)

Tags: php, image

Context:

I am currently working on retrieving an image from my server for a digital email signature. I have made a php file that when called returns an image. That image changes if someone is online in a widget via XML. My img source goes to my php file `<img src="http://www.robin-widget.com/mailHandtekening/present-image.php" border="0"/>` . That php file shows an img, this img changes with an XML condition.

My problem:

In Gmail, the img src can not be a php file, it must be a img file like .png. Even though my .php file works in a browser it does not work in gmail because gmail changes the url so it must be a .png.

Question:

So my question is can that .php file be a .png file or is there any other way in doing this?

Php file:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://test.com/presence/GetPresenceXml?url=https://test.com/name";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $presence = $xml->status[0];

    if ($presence == 'offline'){
        $img = "https://www.robin-widget.com/mailHandtekening/images/cody.png";
    } else {
        $img = "https://www.robin-widget.com/mailHandtekening/images/cody_online.png";
    }

    $fp = fopen($img, 'rb');

    // send the right headers
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($img));

    // dump the picture and stop the script
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
?>
```

If anyone needs more information about my question I am most definitely willing to answer it.

UPDATE:
I've figured out how to update a picture in a email client. My original question was that I wanted to change that .php file into a .png file. I've done this by redirecting a random .png file my .php script that updates the picture. It worked but it didn't in email clients, google still blocked it. (Google changes the original im src link to their own for security reasons). What i've done now is making a php script that writes a picture to my server. This php script gets executed every one minute with cronjobs. (Note that in the .htacces image caching must be off since only the image it self changes not the name of the image).

Comment: If you are using apache, you can edit your config to make it interpret certain extensions (e.g. png) as php files, if that's what you mean.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is, that once the image got downloaded (e.g. with an email client, not webmail) it probably won't get updated anymore. You might be able to counteract that with web mail-clients by setting a couple of http-headers like `Cache-Control: no-cache`.